# TSQL - FOR XML add data to the root node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xdOthPay]
(
    AccountNo char(10) NOT NULL,
    PaymentDoneOn datetime NULL,
    PaymentDoneBy char(30) NULL,
    InvoiceNumber char(10) NULL,
    AmountPaid decimal(12,3) NULL,
    Comments char(254) NULL,
    ClientID char(50) NULL,
    InstallID char(50) NULL,
    BatchID char(14) NOT NULL 
)
```

That I need to export regularly via SSIS and SFTP.

The receiver of the export specifies this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Payments ClientId="10865" xmlns="http://someUrl.com/core/xml/payment">
    <Payment>
        <AccountNo>VALUE</AccountNo>
        <PaymentDoneOn>VALUE</PaymentDoneOn>
        <PaymentDoneBy>VALUE</PaymentDoneBy>
        <InvoiceNumber>VALUE</InvoiceNumber>
        <AmountPaid>VALUE</AmountPaid>
        <Comments>VALUE</Comments>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
```

This is my T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    AccountNo,
    PaymentDoneOn,
    PaymentDoneBy,
    InvoiceNumber,
    AmountPaid,
    Comments
FROM 
    xdMOBOthPay
FOR XML PATH ('Payment'), ROOT ('Payments'), ELEMENTS
```

This results in:

```
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <AccountNo> 972140</AccountNo>
        <PaymentDoneOn>2017-06-08T00:00:00</PaymentDoneOn>
        <PaymentDoneBy>R Entry BA13177 </PaymentDoneBy>
        <InvoiceNumber> 3804</InvoiceNumber>
        <AmountPaid>468.000</AmountPaid>
        <Comments>Non-Onl Payment </Comments>
    </Payment>
...
```

Which is very close, but I need to get the data into the Root element (Payments). The column in the table `ClientID` needs to be included in the root element as the `ClientID` attribute. The `ClientID` will be consistent on all rows for the table.

I have explored several approaches but I am not getting to format required.

Thanks
Torin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you not to use fixed width char columns, rather use varchar columns. The sample adds the namespace and does the XML slightly different to get everything as you need. The sample does this for one specific `ClientID`, I suppose that is what you need.

The result has an unfortunate thing, where the namespace is also applied to the `Payment` element. If that's not acceptable, there is a workaround where you would generate without the XML namespace, and where you would apply string functions to insert the namespace attribute.

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE #xdOthPay(
    AccountNo char(10) NOT NULL,
    PaymentDoneOn datetime NULL,
    PaymentDoneBy char(30) NULL,
    InvoiceNumber char(10) NULL,
    AmountPaid decimal(12,3) NULL,
    Comments char(254) NULL,
    ClientID char(50) NULL,
    InstallID char(50) NULL,
    BatchID char(14) NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO #xdOthPay(AccountNo,AmountPaid,BatchID,ClientID,Comments,InstallID,InvoiceNumber,PaymentDoneBy,PaymentDoneOn)
VALUES(972140,468,'bath-id',10865,'comments','install-id','invoicenr','paymentdoneby','20170101'),
      (972141,468,'bath-id',10865,'comments','install-id','invoicenr','paymentdoneby','20170101');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://someUrl.com/core/xml/payment')
SELECT 
    10865 AS '@clientId',
    (
        SELECT 
            AccountNo,
            PaymentDoneOn,
            PaymentDoneBy,
            InvoiceNumber,
            AmountPaid,
            Comments
        FROM 
            #xdOthPay AS i
        WHERE
            i.ClientID=10865
        FOR 
            XML PATH ('Payment'), TYPE
    )
FOR 
    XML PATH ('Payments'), ELEMENTS;

DROP TABLE #xdOthPay;
```

Result:

```
<Payments xmlns="http://someUrl.com/core/xml/payment" clientId="10865">
  <Payment xmlns="http://someUrl.com/core/xml/payment">
    <AccountNo>972140    </AccountNo>
    <PaymentDoneOn>2017-01-01T00:00:00</PaymentDoneOn>
    <PaymentDoneBy>paymentdoneby                 </PaymentDoneBy>
    <InvoiceNumber>invoicenr </InvoiceNumber>
    <AmountPaid>468.000</AmountPaid>
    <Comments>comments                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </Comments>
  </Payment>
  <Payment xmlns="http://someUrl.com/core/xml/payment">
    <AccountNo>972141    </AccountNo>
    <PaymentDoneOn>2017-01-01T00:00:00</PaymentDoneOn>
    <PaymentDoneBy>paymentdoneby                 </PaymentDoneBy>
    <InvoiceNumber>invoicenr </InvoiceNumber>
    <AmountPaid>468.000</AmountPaid>
    <Comments>comments                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </Comments>
  </Payment>
</Payments>
```

Comment: Hi @TT., from the question I'd assume, that there might be several `<Payment>` nodes below `<Payments>`... And you are right of course, that `CHAR` schould be replaced with `VARCHAR`. Alternatively one might use `RTRIM()`.

Comment: @Shnugo Ah yes, that may give the wrong XML, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Shnugo I started out differently, with a subquery to select the Payment element.... only to see that the Payment element also gets the namespace declaration. Sometimes, XML handling in SQL Server is so confusing.

Comment: This is an veeery old, well known and annoying behaviour. You might visit [this connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements). The repeated namespaces are not wrong but bloating the result. There is no good workaround for all situations...

Comment: Most common is the creation *without* root attributes (namespaces and other values). After a cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` these parts are inserted on string level (e.g. using `STUFF`). Then a re-cast to XML. Ugly...

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, I already upvoted that one (a long time ago :)). I'll post without the workaround, see if this enough for the OP.

Comment: Just a tiny hint: It would be easier to put the `Payment` as name into `PATH('Payment')` and ommit all column aliases...

Comment: @Shnugo :D :D :D

Comment: Thank you TT (VERY MUCH).  Your answer got me moving on this project again.  I will have already eliminated the possibility of multiple Payments/ClientID nodes.  If the receiver has an issue with the namespace repeating in each Payment node, I hope to be able to point out that is in within XML specs.